# Why cannot I rosmake the image_pipeline package?

Tags: ros, rosmake, image-view, git

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to use the opencv in my ros, following the tutorials: http: // www .ros.org/wiki/openni_launch, I git cloned the image_view package(actually I use the command:     git clone https :// github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline.git, because image_pipeline includes image_view), however, I can not rosmake the package, it always shows like:

```
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] No package specified.  Building stack ['image_pipeline']            
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['image_pipeline']                          
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/turtlebot/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130408-221329
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['image_pipeline'] to:
[]                             
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The stack "image_proc" was not found. We will assume it is using the new buildsystem and try to continue...
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The stack "image_view" was not found. We will assume it is using the new buildsystem and try to continue...
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The stack "image_rotate" was not found. We will assume it is using the new buildsystem and try to continue...
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The stack "stereo_image_proc" was not found. We will assume it is using the new buildsystem and try to continue...
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The stack "depth_image_proc" was not found. We will assume it is using the new buildsystem and try to continue...
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The stack "camera_calibration" was not found. We will assume it is using the new buildsystem and try to continue...
```

anybody knows how to deal with it? thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60220/why-cannot-i-rosmake-the-image_pipeline-package?/) by [David_xiong](https://answers.ros.org/users/4573/david_xiong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-04-08**:
You should try turning off capslock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The default branch (groovy-devel) of image_pipeline uses the new buildsystem, [catkin](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin), so you need to use catkin to build it, instead of rosbuild.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2013-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3